# How does \special know which output driver it's addressing?

Tags: tex-core, syntax

The TeXbook says that `\special{…}`is a special instruction to the output driver. But how do you know when you write the instruction which output driver will be reading it?

Comment: `\special` doesn't know, it just passes stuff ahead.   You (the programmer) has to know beforehand which backend you are targetting (usually, but not always by knowing which engine you are running on) and write the appropriate instructions in `\special`.

Comment: as Phelype says.  That is why packages like color, graphics, hyperref, ... have "driver options" If you use `[dvips]` latex writes the specials in dvips syntax, and the dvi  file is not  usable with othr drivers

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2):

`\special` doesn't know about the backend, it just passes stuff ahead.  The TeXBook says:

> `\special` `<general text>`. The balanced text is expanded and put into a “whatsit” item, which is appended to the current list. The text will eventually appear in the `dvi` file as an instruction to subsequent software.

which means that other than expanding the `<general text>`, TeX does no processing after that, and just ships the expanded `<general text>` to a whatsit node, that is included as-is in the (back then only) `dvi` file.

With newer engines you have different output formats (e.g., PDF on pdfTeX and LuaTeX, and `xdv` on XeTeX), but TeX knows nothing about that.  You (the programmer) has to know beforehand which backend you are targetting (usually, but not always by knowing which engine you are running on) and write the appropriate instructions in `\special`.

As David says, that's why packages that deal with graphics and colour (for example) use driver files that contain the instructions for each backend.  For example, in `l3backend-pdftex.def` you'll find (something like):

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__draw_backend_lineto:nn #1#2
  { \__draw_backend_literal:x { #1 ~ #2 ~ l } }
```

while in `l3backend-dvips.def` it will look like:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__draw_backend_lineto:nn #1#2
  { \__draw_backend_literal:x { #1 ~ #2 ~ lineto } }
```

(here `\__draw_backend_literal:x` is a wrapper around `\special`).  Then, higher-level code in `l3draw` can simply use `\__draw_backend_lineto:nn` to draw a line without having to worry about which backend to target.  Packages like pict2e, TikZ, graphics, xcolor, hyperref, geometry, etc. all use their own backend-specific files more or less on the same fashion.